# Maven plugin not working in RAD 8.5

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, rad

I have multiple web projects which have inter dependencies. Any Maven action on any module produces the following error.

**An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
org/eclipse/core/runtime/preferences/InstanceScope.INSTANCE**

I tried the following to resolve, but nothing helped.

- cleaned up using mvn clean.
- In the RAD deleted the projects and re-imported them as maven
  projects.

Even tried deleting the workspace metadata. Not sure what is going on. Any help?

Comment: Have you deleted .project,.classpath, .settings after deliting them in RAD and reimported the projects?

Comment: I haven't done that. Will try that and repost if it is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely reinstalled RAD and tried many M2E update sites, everything was erroring out looking for some dependencies. What worked for me is the below site, simple no fuss:

[Sonatype M2E](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e/0.12.1/S/0.12.1.20110112-1712/)

also posting SVN plugin someone looking for both build and version plugins

[SVN eclipse plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by starting RSA whit -clean parameter